# What's the difference of TR-069 and Point-To-Point protocol?

Tags: isp, adsl, point-to-point, atm

I've read my ISP, [Telecom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecom) uses a *Point-to-Point* regarding the ADSL networking over ATM nowadays (which is rarely used in my country, and it's non-commercial). My friend told me it actually uses TR-069, is it true? Obviously, he isn't completely certain of what he said.

What's the actual difference? What method does Telecom actually use? I think it is an highly country-dependent answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confused with the terms Point to Point and TR-069 here.

An ISP normally uses IPOE/PPPOE/PPPOA for establishing the connectivity between CPE(Modem/Gateway) and their BRAS. They also use their own radius server to authenticate the PPP connection for obvious reasons.

TR-069 is a mechanism to provision a Gateway/Modem with the respective plan(End customer plans based on their chosen plan) and other operation from the network operator point of view.TR-069 also can be used to fetch the complete data model of the Modem and operator can pretty much read and write(only Writable Parameters) from the CPE.

In addition to this,ISP will also set a periodic inform counter in which CPE will also send periodic Inform with information such as Model number,Software version and other details towards ISP's ACS(Access Control System). This is how ISP understand the firmware version of the CPE and trigger a Software upgrade on a scheduled basis.

TR-069 can also be used for ISP to trigger Remote Procedure calls where CPE will trigger WiFi Scan,GET,Set, etc operations.

**On a layman perspective, PPP is L2 protocol and TR-069 is an application layer protocol.**

I will be more happy to provide more detailed answer for any queries regarding CWMP or TR-069.Let me know if you need more info on this.

Comment: So, basically PPP is normally used to enstablish the connection, and then the PPP can be PPOE, PPOA or IPOE?

Comment: Exactly. PPP is used to establish the connection and that is the protocol which carries back and forth your actual data(Browsing,Streatming,VOIP).TR-069 in the other side a protocol defined by broadband forum for controlling your CPE(customer premise equipmet),Troubleshooting the issues on the CPE and perform their regular scheduled Software upgrades. The default port for TR-069 is 7547.It supports both http and https for communication between CPE and ACS. I hope now you have the clear picture :) IPOE is not a Point to Point protocol.It is a different protocol normally works with DHCP.